# Print an image in C++ on the Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, printing

I am building a C++ plugin on the Mac os/x using Xcode.  The code is entirely c++ and I need to print an image to the default printer.  I'm new to mac programming unfortunately and haven't seen any pure c++ examples that can take an image and send it to the default printer without any user interaction.  I have seen some examples in Objective-C .m files but I am unsure of how to utilize that from a C++ function which is called from the browser.  Does anyone have any code snippets to take an image (file or URL) and issue the print?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to avoid Objective-C (and you really should not limit yourself like this), the way to print things in MacOS is to use the lower level API's available in ["Core Printing", which is a part of the Application Services framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/Reference/reference.html).

You'd open up a session via [`PMCreateSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/PMCreateSession), do your printing to that session and then release that session via [`PMRelease`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CorePrintRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/PMRelease).  There may be some useful sample code available named ["Quartz2DBasics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Quartz2DBasics/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003975).

If the list of API's is too intimidating, things might feel a lot more friendly if you use the higher level API's available in the Objective-C based frameworks. And you ***can*** call Objective C methods from C++ or Objective-C++ files (these are files that end with the "`.mm`" extension).